# Subdomain cookie maintenance for Forms authentication website

Tags: authentication, binding, subdomain, session-cookies

I have a Server on Azure where an MVC4 web application is hosted. On the server I have added bindings for:

```
company1.mysite.com
company2.mysite.com
```

Within mysite an Admin user has the option to define custom styles for each of the subdomains. So to check the changes have been applied successfully. If the admin changes the URL from company1.mysite.com to company2.mysite.com they are redirected back to a login page. When I then attempt to log in with the same details it seems that there is some conflict in the cookies and I am unable to find the user details.

Is there anyway that I could preserve the login details for one subdomain and allow the user to simply change the URL to see if the changes had been supplied effectively. If not is there any way I can prevent this conflict on signing on to the other subdomain?

Comment: I think you question can be related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Comment: this lead me to the correct answer please put it as an answer and I will accept cheers

Comment: welcome, i've added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cookie domain must be specified in a proper way. Please, see [this link](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm)